# Interpolate Line Tool giving different results?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcgis-10.6, inverse-distance-weighted, profile

I have been using 'Interpolate Line' Tool in the 3D Analyst tool pack to create a profile graph so I can analyze interpolated results gathered from an IDW created surface. However, when I use the tool in the same spot (has the same X Y starting point and the same width each time) at different times, I will obtain different profile graphs each time.

For example, the first time I used this tool, I created a line with a starting point of xxx,xxx m E, x,xxx,xxx m N with a length of 34,500 m. I obtained this profile graph from the first trial. [image]

The second time I used this tool, with the same starting point and width as the first line, I obtained this profile graph.
 [image]

Can anyone explain why this is, or how I can fix it?

Comment: Line in the same point and width? Both make no sense, please reword.

Comment: Do you perhaps have any selected item when you run the tool? Make sure to clear any active selection and the tool should give you the right result.

Comment: Do you mean selection of the surface in the Table of Contents?  Because that is the only selection I have made. I also made sure that each time I used the tool, the correct layer was selected in the 3D Analyst tool bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined through further research that once you have created the line on the surface, it doesn't update the data/profile graph if you change the location/length of the line. So each of the profile graphs I created above were from slightly different locations and when I updated the location of the line, it did not update the profile. There is no current fix for this, so I'm looking at alternate ways to derive my profile graph.